# How webpack vendors import part of a module?

Tags: webpack

In my webpack config file, I have the following config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var base = path.join(__dirname);

var vendors = [
  'antd',
  'autobind-decorator',
  'babel-polyfill',
  'classnames',
  'moment',
  'rc-select',
  'react',
  'react-bootstrap',
  'react-bootstrap-validation',
  'react-datetime',
  'react-dom',
  'react-mixin',
  'react-router',
  'reflux',
  'reqwest',
  'tiny-cookie'
];

module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  output: {
    path: `${base}/dist`,
    library: '[name]_[chunkhash]',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  entry: {
    vendor: vendors,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({
      path: 'manifest.json',
      name: '[name]_[chunkhash]',
      context: __dirname,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
         NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
       }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        },
        except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require']
    }),
  ],
};
```

In my jsx I know:

```
   import {Icon} from antd;
```

But here I want to compile the vendor into webpack dll, so I just want to import some components of antd, not the whole module. What can I do?

Comment: Question title should be "How can webpack entry import part of module ?"